# How do you update a column to a foreign key?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE enrolled
(
  sid integer NOT NULL,
  ccode character varying(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT enrolled_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY (sid, ccode)
);
```

Now I want to UPDATE the *ccode* column to be declared as a foreign key from a table called Class. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY enrolled
    ADD CONSTRAINT enrolled_ccode_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ccode)
        REFERENCES class(ccode)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

But for this to work remember, that you must have a unique index on the `class.ccode` column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX class_ccode_idx ON class USING btree (ccode);
```

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks.